# MySQL error - Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '' for column

Tags: php, mysql, macos, datetime

I am using mysql in Os X 10.9.2 and when I try to run my php website in local I have this error:

Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '' for column nameOfTheColumn

The Error happens when I tried to insert an empty value in a datetime field. The site works fine in production and in some other locals computers, so the problem is in database and I have to be solve in my local database. Reading about the problem I read that mysql could be running in Strict mode, so I edit /usr/local/mysql/my.cnf and I comment out this line:

```
 #sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

I restart computer and still is not working, but according to the documentation online and others questions, this is the way, but I would like to know What is it the exactly change I have to do to make my application works. Repeat, the code works in production, windows with xampp, etc... so can not be change because is to long and just for work in local I need the right change in MYSQL DATABASE.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: does your datetime column allow null ?

Comment: Yes It does, but I repeat the site works well in production and in other locations like my windows PC with xampp. I can not change the database structure and the code. The problem is in mysql configuration, I read about this but at the end I do not know what it is the exactly change I have to do in my.cnf or other related file.

Comment: have you already thought of simply copying the mysql configuration from one of the working installations onto your computer? don't forget to modify the pathes for mysql datadir, sockets accordingly.

Comment: @developer even if I insert value '' for datetime column, it does not throw any error rather converts to '0000-00-00 00:00:00'. Even I did not comment the sql_mode. There might be other problem

Answer (score 9):

It looks like the default sql_mode on your osx instance of MySQL is set to refuse invalid dates.

You could try issuing this command:

```
SET SESSION sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES'
```

as you initialize your session.

Comment: Perfect! I had to use this to run an update to change some invalid datetimes *to* valid ones...

Answer (score 0):

you can change your column to allow null

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY datetime_column_name datetime;
```

Columns are nullable by default as long as a column is not declared as NOT NULL.

Comment: I only want to add [from manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html): _For all engines, a UNIQUE index permits multiple NULL values for columns that can contain NULL._

Comment: how does a unique column allow multiple null values ?

Comment: Even if a column is nullable, as by your statement, there's no problem to create a unique index. NULL values don't count as duplicates.

Comment: The engine is simply not checking the unique contraint in that case. `NULL` means “a missing unknown value” and it is treated somewhat differently from other values. [Read more about the concept of `NULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/working-with-null.html) and the [problems that may arise when using or not understanding it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/problems-with-null.html) in the MySQL Manual.

Answer (score 0):

At last I found the solution, in fact I was on the way, the solution is to comment out sql_mode, but the file located in /etc/my.cnf instead of /usr/local/mysql/my.cnf. If you do not comment this line, and you try to insert an empty value an error is raised, but if you comment it out, empty values becomes '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar issue on our MySQL 5.6 server.
When I changed `sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` to `sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` - the issue was fixed.

Of course, it is a good idea to be sure that the value is in the correct format.
For example, if the column type is "DATETIME", but in php we try to insert the value generated by `date('c')` - we'll get that error (if strict mode is turned on). But when we'll change it to: `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` - the issue is gone.